# Creating a raster and setting extent in R

Tags: raster, r, rasterization

I am trying to create a raster with 922 columns and 444 rows at 0.06250-degree spatial resolution. However, after I set the following extent the resolution of the resulting raster comes out to be 0.06243221. It seems like the extent function is only reading the first 4 digits after the decimal for both xmn and xmx.

Here is a sample code I am trying:

```
r <- raster(ncol=922, nrow=444)

bb <- extent(235.40625,292.96875,25.15625, 52.84375)

extent(r) <- bb

r <- setExtent(r, bb)
```

I have also tried to only set the extent and resolution but then I only get 921 columns and 443 rows.

```
r <- raster()
bb <- extent(235.40625,292.96875,25.15625, 52.84375)
extent(r) <- bb
res(r) <-0.06250
r <- setExtent(r, bb)
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 3):

After going back and fourth, it seems like the extent values are for the lower left corner and not the center of the lower left cell. So, subtracting 0.0625/2 from xmin and ymin and adding 0.0625/2 to xmax and ymax solved the problem.

Comment: Could you edit this post and add the complete set of code you ended up with, commented?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is a decimals or calculation problems in your parameters, and they don't match, also 0.0625 is equal to 0.06250. You can set all the parameters at once:

```
ra <- raster( ncol=922, nrow=444, 
              res = 0.06250, 
              ext = extent(235.40625,292.96875,25.15625, 52.84375))

> ra
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 443, 921, 408003  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.0625, 0.0625  (x, y)
extent     : 235.4062, 292.9688, 25.15625, 52.84375  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```